# Having to use window.variableName and not sure why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I am using JS, Angular, and Meteor to develop a web app that uses the Youtube api. In the constructor of one of my controllers I create the youtube player object by following the youtube api process. However, when I try to reference the seemingly global "player" object in a later function within the same controller, it appears to be out of scope.

I was wrestling with this issue for days because the "player" variable seems to be global (there is no var proceeding it) until I ran across the frowned upon practice of using window.variableName. I can only get the playPause function to recognize the player object if I use window.player = ... Does anyone have any idea why the player object is not already global to its containing controller and functions?

I am still learning my way around javascript scoping intricacies as well as ECMA class style, so any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import Ionic from 'ionic-scripts';
import { _ } from 'meteor/underscore';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { MeteorCameraUI } from 'meteor/okland:camera-ui';
import { Controller } from 'angular-ecmascript/module-helpers';
import { Chats, Messages } from '../../../lib/collections';

export default class ChatCtrl extends Controller {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.currentVideoId = this.$stateParams.videoId;
    this.chatId = this.$stateParams.chatId;

    this.isIOS = Ionic.Platform.isWebView() && Ionic.Platform.isIOS();
    this.isCordova = Meteor.isCordova;
    chat = Chats.findOne(this.chatId);

    if (chat.playerType == "Y") {
      window.player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        videoId: this.currentVideoId,
        events: {
                  'onReady': this.initTimes.bind(this)
              }
      });
    } else if (chat.playerType == "V") {

      var options = {
        id: this.currentVideoId,
        width: 640,
        loop: false
      };

      var player = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-placeholder', options);
    }

  playPauseToggle() {
    if (player.getPlayerState() == 2 || player.getPlayerState() == 5) {
      player.playVideo();
      this.playPauseValue = "Pause";
    } else if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
      player.pauseVideo();
      this.playPauseValue = "Play";
    }
  }

ChatCtrl.$name = 'ChatCtrl';
ChatCtrl.$inject = ['$stateParams', '$timeout', '$ionicScrollDelegate', '$ionicPopup', '$log'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you define your player as a local variable in your class constructor. As such, that variable will not be visible anywhere else - like in your playPauseToggle function.

Instead, why not make your player an attribute of your class instance?

```
this.player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder'...
```

and then

```
playPauseToggle() {
    if (this.player.getPlayerState() == 2 || this.player.getPlayerState() == 5) {
    ... // replace all occurrences of 'player' with 'this.player'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been doing this everywhere else in my code. For some reason I forgot to add "this" when declaring player and it never registered to me when trying to debug.

Comment: Sure thing - no worries!